# how to check gltf model lightning after loading in aframe?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have a gltf model with lightning information, in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ it looks like:
[image]

after I import it like :

```
         <a-asset-item id="meeting_room" src="https://cdn.glitch.me/a8291825-29e8-463c-aa81-b88bf9bbe58c/changjing_v03.gltf?v=1657000875278"></a-asset-item>
...
    <a-gltf-model position="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" src="#meeting_room"></a-gltf-model>
```

it looks like:
[image]

Question: where and how to enable the gltf light source? I don't see light entity in the inspector  besides the aframe default light. if I turn off the aframe light entity off, it turns out all black.

a demo glitch is here: [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/vaulted-fork-chair)

20220705：
I try

```
<a-scene renderer="
               colorManagement: true;">
```

but cant get gltf lights as well.

update 20220706

[image]

as Piotr Adam Milewski and Mugen87 mention, in lightning setting in gltf viewer, there is environment light and "add lights", which add a ambient and a direction light to the scene. the environment light is from gltf export, which needs to open a environment light in THREEJS. how about the "add lights" ambient and direction light? is from gltf file or the gltfviewer? if it's from gltf file, how to check it's position color or intensity things?

Comment: In plain `three.js` you should be able to achieve a similar lighting by assigning a HDR environment map to `Scene.environment`. It's required to enable tone mapping in this case. I'm not sure how both can be done with A-Frame though.

Comment: If You set `environment` to `None` in the gltf viewer, and it looks like in the `a-frame` scene, then it's like Mugen says - you need to load a HDR environment map ( afaik just like in THREE, just from a custom component )

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski, thanks for the reply, did you mean that the enviroment light in gltf viewer is from gltf file, which works like a environment light. what about the "add lights" ambient and direction light in gltf viewer, is from gltf file or added by gltf viewer?

Comment: The light is not defined in the glTF asset. You have to load an additional texture that you use for image-based lighting. Optionally, you can further add an ambient and directional light, but it is not necessarily required. The scene will look good with just an environment map.